# Как обрезать число с префиксом "0"?

Tags: дата, bat

Мне нужно сделать арифметические операции над месяцами. Некоторые месяцы приходят в формате с предшествующим нулем (август: "08").
Как обрезать при наличии "0"?

Данный код выдает "08", а не желаемое "8". Код внутри IF выполняется, проверял с помощью echo.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET lastlogMM="08"
IF %lastlogMM:~0,1% EQU 0 (SET !lastlogMM!=%lastlogMM:~1%)
echo %lastlogMM%
```

Comment: под " Код внутри IF" я имел ввиду то что внутри скобок "SET !lastlogMM!=%lastlogMM:~1%"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убрав восклицательные знаки, получим нормальное присвоение переменной окружения нужного значения.

```
IF %lastlogMM:~0,1% EQU 0 (SET lastlogMM=%lastlogMM:~1%)
```

Comment: А убрав кавычки во второй строке, ещё и избавимся от проблемы при присвоении начального значения.

Comment: вторая строка служит чисто для демрстрации. Мне передаються данные в подобном виде. Но спасибо за совет.